# How do I sort data in grid based on field that has unique number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, grid, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid connected to API. There's an ID column which has a unique number, its been generated in database with this format: YYYYMMDDXXX

The first four digits are a full year, then month, and day. XXX are a random letters.
As we know from that format, the first 8 digits are date identifier (today date). And then random letters

How do I sorted them?
I mean every time I generate that number, it entered to the grid and the newest always on the bottom. For instance:

1. 20190226BLA
2. 20190226ZKA
3. 20190226RRN
4. 20190227BAM
5. 20190228CAA

I want it becomes:

1. 20190228CAA
2. 20190227BAM
3. 20190226RRN
4. 20190226ZKA
5. 20190226BLA

How I do that? Please help. I saw stackoverflow's logo, an I got an idea using stack data structure. But How? Or any simple idea?

there's a data field from API called created_date. Should I sort with it?

```
                       $.ajax({
                                method: 'POST',
                                url: MyAPILink,
                                data: JSON.stringify(arg),
                                dataType: 'json',
                                contentType: 'application/json',
                            }).done(function (resp){
                                // console.log(resp)
                                if(resp.data != null){
                                    var nameArray = [];
                                    $.each(resp.data,function(key,val){
                                        nameArray.push({
                                            idNumber: val.id,
                                            supplierName: val.supplier,
                                            DueDate: val.limit_payment_date,
                                            status: val.status,
                                            is_paid: val.is_paid,
                                            amount: val.amount
                                        });
                                    });
                                    nameArray.sort(function (a, b) {
                                        return b.id - a.id
                                    });
                                    option.success({
                                        data: nameArray,
                                        total: resp.total
                                    })
                                }

                            }).fail(function(jqXHR, status, err){
                                option.error(err);
                            });
```

Comment: You can sort them using [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). If you are struggling with this, please show your current HTML and JS code so we can help you debug it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm sorry, I forget. Here's my update. I'm going to sort it in ajax request before its apply on my grid. I just updated my question. I input my code there

Answer (score 0):

If the data is in array then you can just [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) it.

```js
const arr = ["20190226BLA",
  "20190226ZKA",
  "20190226RRN",
  "20190227BAM",
  "20190228CAA",
]
console.log(arr.reverse())
```

Comment: Well, thank you. It works but, there's a problem. I show 10 data per page in grid. Your solution sort data per page. What I want is sort to all entire data in grid. So, if one day in April, I enter a new data, it will show on the first page, on the first row, and 20190226BLA will be in the last page, in the last row